# Replacing corrupt e-mail addresses in a file, using PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a file file.txt containing a list of emails

```
email@domain.com
email@domain2.com
email@domain3.com
email@domain4.com
email@domain5.com
@domain.com
email@domain6.com
email@domain7.com
```

I need to remove @domain.com from the list. I am using this code:

```
file_put_contents('file.txt',
                  str_replace("@domain.com","",file_get_contents('file.txt')));
```

But this also removes `@domain.com` from `email@domain.com`, making it an incorrect list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use regex to match a whole line. From the top of my head this would be:

```
<?php
file_put_contents('file.txt',
                  preg_replace("/^@domain\.com$/m","",file_get_contents('file.txt')));
```

If you want to delete the line instead of making it empty the regex would be `"/^@domain\.com[\n]$/m"`

Comment: You could probably use that method. But it seems that method is deprecated (as said in http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg-replace.php). So it's best to use preg_replace (or preg_replace_all)

Comment: You have to escape the dot becau it means any character.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that.. I'll edit my post :)

Answer (score 0):

You could determine the position of the @ sign and replace only if it's the first character in the line.

```
function replacethis($file){
    $str = '';
    $a = file_get_contents($file);
    foreach ($a as $b) {
        if (strpos($b,'@') == 0) {
            $str .= str_replace('@domain.com','',$b)."<br>"; }
        else {
            $str .= $b."<br>";
        }}
    return $str;

}
file_put_contents('file.txt', replacethis('file.txt'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use preg_replace: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php on each line.

This will remove every e-mail address, which does not have username at the beginning.

```
$file = new SplFileObject("file.txt");
$emailAddresses = array();
while (!$file->eof()) {
    $email = trim(preg_replace("/^@(.*)$/", "", $file->fgets())); // If you only want to remove specific addresses from a specific domain, change (.*) to domain\.com

    if (strlen($email)) {
        $emailAddresses [] = $email;
    }
}
file_put_contents("file.txt", join(PHP_EOL, $emailAddresses));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using a regex something like `(^@domain\.com)` should replace only @domain.com if the @ is the begining of the sentence

Comment: you can use preg_replace but i didnt write the code as im not a php developer i just knew a regex that would do the job and hope you could fill in the bits around it